# Matrix-array error with CalcularCoeficientes

Tags: java, arrays

I have the below code:

```
double[][] Coeficientes;
double[] VectorCoeficientes = new double[13];

int z = 0;
for(int i=0; i<longVector-LventanaReal; i+=saltos){
    VectorCoeficientes = CalcularCoeficientes(i);  (Step1)
    Coeficientes[z] = VectorCoeficientes;   (Step2)
    z++;
}
```

CalcularCoeficientes gives me an array which has a length of 13, then the Step1 works well, but I can't do the Step2, I want save that array in a matrix Coeficientes.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Compilation error? Runtime error? Strange output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an initialization of your `Coeficientes` array.

change :

```
double[][] Coeficientes;
```

to :

```
double[][] Coeficientes = new double[someLength][]; // where someLength is some
                                                    // int value that determines
                                                    // the number of rows in your
                                                    // matrix
```

Only then you'll be able to run the assignment :

```
Coeficientes[z] = VectorCoeficientes;
```

If the number of rows is unknown, use a `List<double[]>` and convert the List to a matrix in the end:

```
double[][] Coeficientes;
List<double[]> temp = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i<longVector-LventanaReal; i+=saltos){
    double[] VectorCoeficientes = CalcularCoeficientes(i);
    temp.add(VectorCoeficientes);
}

Coeficientes = temp.toArray(new double[temp.size()][13]);
```

Comment: I want a matrix like this: Coeficientes[(I don't know)][13]; How can i inializate it?

Comment: @cedra If you don't know the number of rows, you can't initialize it. You can use a `List<double[]>` to store an unknown number of rows, and convert it to a matrix in the end.